# issue regarding positioning div using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i have one fixed div and that is placed on page using css. i have another div which is dynamically generated and added into form and position at center of page. this div added when click occur on document.

the problem is when i click on document the div dynamically added onto page and position properly but the static div position getting change. i just do not understand why it happens.
[here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/5R4g2/)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).click(function (e) {
                // Check for left button click
                if (e.button == 0) {
                    $('form').append('<div id="dvfloat" class="float_div">Welcome</div>').center().fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });

            jQuery.fn.center = function () {
                this.css("position", "absolute");
                this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) +
                                                $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
                this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) +
                                                $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
                return this;
            }
        });
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
.login_div {
    background-color: Yellow;
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}
.float_div {
    background-color: Green;
    width: 100px;
    height:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="static_dv" class="login_div"> hi how r u ? </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

please run my code and see the effect. static div called "static_dv" getting re-position when i click on document but i did not write any code to do so. i want static div should change its position. what will be the fix. thanks

Comment: do u think this problem occur due to jquery version?

Comment: @Thomas, probably just curious why you're using such an old version.

Comment: i change the version still got the same error

Comment: Problem is not version of js, problem of setting styles to tags. See my code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually centering the newly created DIV, but the whole form, try with this little change:

```
$('form').append('<div id="dvfloat" class="float_div">Welcome</div>').fadeIn('slow');
$('#dvfloat').center();
```

Comment: can u please tell me why my green color div is not appearing when i am running my script from jsfiddle. here is the url http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/Aub2z/ if possible please have a look and tell me the reason. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your div inside in form, in your js you changed position FORM, so all content were changed too

try this

```
 var div = $('<div id="dvfloat" class="float_div">Welcome</div>');
 $('FORM').append(div)
 div.center().fadeIn('slow');
```

You need to set position of div, but constraction of ($TAG).append($someTag) - return $TAG, so you set central position to  $TAG

Comment: can u please tell me why my green color div is not appearing when i am running my script from jsfiddle. here is the url http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/Aub2z/ if possible please have a look and tell me the reason. thanks

Comment: You removed tag "form", if you need to achive this affect you need to add this div to BODY tag. And set position to new div. If you want that two tags have diferent position they should be at leas ton one level. But in your case you added in form. FROM doesnt have Height:100% and width:100%, so there is no place for new tag. Add new tag into BODY

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
Your "this" refers to the form, and you are changing the position of the form and hence not working. Use the new code below which references the div instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        // Check for left button click
        if (e.button == 0) {
            $('form').append('<div id="dvfloat" class="float_div">Welcome</div>').center().fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });

    jQuery.fn.center = function() {
        this.find('.float_div').css("position", "absolute");
        this.find('.float_div').css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.find('.float_div').outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
        this.find('.float_div').css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.find('.float_div').outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
        return this;
    }
});​
```